# How to show two toasts in SweetAlert2: Async/Await problem

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I have an `AJAX` call where for the response I get an array of messages. I use `SweetAlert2` to show the messages, and I'd like to show the messages one after another using `await`; however, it doesn't work. I just get the first sweetalert toast, and for the second I run into the error saying 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is undefined'. May you please help catch what is wrong here and how to solve it.

PS. By showing the message one after another I mean all the messages be shown automatically after another. No user input is needed, and looked for. Each toast takes three seconds to get dismissed. Just after this I want the next to be shown.

```
success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status === '110') {
                        greenSwal('Done.');
                    } else {
                        $.each(data.msg, async function (i, item) {
                            if (item === '2') {
                                await Swal.fire({
                                    icon: 'success',
                                    title: 'Success'
                                })
                            }
                            if (item === '1') {
                                await Swal.fire({
                                    icon: 'error',
                                    title: 'Error'
                                })
                            }

                        });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Define "one after the other"--what determines when an alert is "done"? User input? `async` doesn't do anything *(useful)* if the function after it isn't asynchronous *(and nothing else depends on promisification)*. Things would need to be restructured if you want, say, the "next" message to show up after the first is dismissed.

Comment: dear @DaveNewton. Thanks. I just modified the question to answer your question. Then, how can I restructure the code?

Comment: No clue. Seems like you want toasts/popups, not dialog boxes, though, if you want multiple messages shown.

Comment: dear @DaveNewton, I am precisely talking about toasts.